# Newly downloaded Eclipse installer is making me use Java 11+

Tags: java, eclipse

This wouldn't be a problem for a lot of people, but I NEED to use Java 8 (jre1.8.0_261). Whenever I launch the installer (I also tried installing the DSL kit all at once) it is forcing me to use Java 11+. Mind you, I don't have any version of Java that is 11 or higher. the only installed version I have is Java 8.

What the installer looks like for me:
[image: installer screen-shot].

Comment: What happens if you just choose the folder of an older JDK? Java 11 is recommended but not necessary.

Comment: You got it wrong. Java 11 is only required to run Eclipse, but of course you can still write Java 8 or even lower code with Eclipse 2020-09. In Eclipse you can even have multiple JDKs installed and use different JDKs from different Java versions in projects.

Comment: @Milgo Java 11 is the minimum requirement to run 2020-09, it will not run with older versions of Java. But as the other comments and answers say that doesn't mean you can't develop programs for older versions of Java.

Answer (score 2):

> Java 11 or higher is needed for *running* Eclipse, not for the programs
> that you *write* in Eclipse. I am developing Java 8 programs using
> Eclipse 2020-09 on top of Java 15. It works very well. And the Oracle
> license does allow this use of Java 15 for free.

– Ole V.V.